# Save Object back to the database

Tags: c#, database, oop

I am working on a project where I am converting some VB.Net class libraries to C# libraries (mostly to learn C# syntax). My problem is that I cannot get the Save function working.

I am building my object with this:

```
    public static StoreEmployee Create(string LoginId)
    {
        var emp = new StoreEmployee();
        using (var dt = DAC.ExecuteDataTable("usp_ActiveEmployeeSelect", 
            DAC.Parameter(CN_LoginId, LoginId)))
        {
            emp.StoreId = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0][CN_StoreId]);
            emp.FirstName = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0][CN_FirstName]);
            emp.LastName = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0][CN_LastName]);
            emp.UserName = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0][CN_UserName]);
            emp.Role = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0][CN_Role]);
            emp.Description = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0][CN_Description]);
        }
        return emp;
    }
```

And then creating it with this

```
    private static void FillStoreEmployeeObject(string empLoginId)
    {
        StoreEmployee.Create(empLoginId);
    }
```

And then trying to use this save function to save the object back to the database:

```
    public override Boolean Save(string LoginId)
    {
        try
        {
            int retVal = DAC.ExecuteNonQuery("usp_ActiveEmployeeSave",
                DAC.Parameter(CN_LoginId, LoginId),
                DAC.Parameter(CN_StoreId, StoreId),
                DAC.Parameter(CN_FirstName, FirstName),
                DAC.Parameter(CN_UserName, UserName),
                DAC.Parameter(CN_Role, Role),
                DAC.Parameter(CN_Description, Description));
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I don't get a syntax warning for that but I have revised it many times so I want to make sure that is correct before I move on. Does this look correct? By the way I am trying to call the Save function with this

StoreEmployee.Save(Convert.ToString(Login))

which gives me this error **An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property** However when I mark my function as static my Create function shows errors so I am left very confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Save` is an *instance method*.

As the error message states,you need to call it on an existing instance of `StoreEmployee` (such as the one returned by `Create`).

Comment: I edited my original question and added my call Create function because now I am wondering if part of my problem is scope. By that I mean to ask is my problem that the StoreEmployee.Save() doesn't have access to the StoreEmployee object because of something I have done wrong?

Comment: **You need to call `Save` on an _instance_ of `StoreEmployee`.**

Comment: I am not real clear on how to do that. I think I understand what you are saying but I am not sure how to get a hold of the StoreEmployee instance after I have created it. Can I create a form level variable that holds the entire StoreEmployee object for as long as I need it?

Comment: I got it now. At the top of my form I added this StoreEmployee emp;, which allows me to hold the StoreEmployee object for as long as I need it. Then it is a matter of creating it with  emp = StoreEmployee.Create(empLoginId); and saving it with emp.Save();. Now all I have to do is verify that my Save function actually works (can't test it now because the database is being modified)